# How to auto fill in text boxes with data from database?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to fill all the text boxes with data that corresponds to the name that is chosed on the dropdown box. I have searched for codes for it to work and unluckily none of it works.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    include("webconfig.php");
    session_start();    
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo_trans.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iconFont.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/metro-bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css">

    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>            
    <script src="js/load-metro.js"></script>

    <!-- Local JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/docs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/github.info.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/metro-dropdown.js"></script>
<title>AS_SIGNS</title>
</head>

<body class="metro">
        <nav class="horizontal-menu" style="background:#037E04;">
            <ul>
             <center><li><a href="index.php"><h1><font color="#FFFFFF">AS Signs</font></h1></a></li></center>
            </ul>
       </nav>

    <div style="width:70%; height:60%; position:absolute; left:0;">
        <div  style="width:100%; height:100%;overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;">
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
            <h2>New Service Call</h2>
            <form method="post" name="form">
                    <table  class="table bordered" width="100%">
                    <tr>    
                        <td>Customer ID</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="custid" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>    
                        <td>Customer Name</td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="CUSTOMER_NAME" style="width:205px" required>
                                <option value="default"></option>
                                 <?php
                                    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER";
                                    $sth = ibase_query($conn, $sql1) or die(ibase_errmsg());

                                    $num = '';

                                    while($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($sth))
                                    {


                                    $name = $row["ACCOUNT_NAME"];

                                    echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";

                                    }
                                ?>


                        </select>
                        </td>   
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="ADDRESS" value="<?php echo "$add"?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

        </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float:right;">
             <h2 style="visibility:hidden;">cqcqcqcqc</h2>
                    <table  class="table bordered" width="100%">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Person</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="CONTACT_PERSON" value="<?php echo "$contperson"?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Number</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="CONTACT_NUMBER" value= "<?php echo "$contnum"?>"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>    
                     <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="SAVE" />
                     <input type="button" name="load" value="LOAD" />

                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['load']))
        {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME = '$name'";
                    $result = ibase_query($query, $conn);
                    $details = ibase_fetch_assoc($result);                                  

                    $sth = ibase_query($conn, $sql) or die(ibase_errmsg());

                    $add = $details["ADDRESS"];
                    $name = $_POST["ACCOUNT_NAME"];
                    $servicenum = $details["SERVICE_CALL_NUMBER"];
                    $contperson = $details["CONTACT_PERSON"];
                    $contnum = $details["CONTACT_NUMBER"];


                    }

                    ?>

                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM SERVICE_REPORTS";


                    $sth = ibase_query($conn, $sql) or die(ibase_errmsg());
                    $add = $_POST["ADDRESS"];
                    $name = $_POST["CUSTOMER_NAME"];
                    $servicenum = $_POST["SERVICE_CALL_NUMBER"];
                    $contperson = $_POST["CONTACT_PERSON"];
                    $contnum = $_POST["CONTACT_NUMBER"];



        if(isset($_POST['btnSave']))
        {

            ibase_query($conn, "INSERT INTO SERVICE_REPORTS (CUSTOMER_NAME, ADDRESS, CONTACT_PERSON, CONTACT_NUMBER) VALUES('$name', '$add', '$contperson', '$contnum')") or die (ibase_errmsg());

            echo "Record Saved";
        }


    ?>
          </form>   
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="span5" style="position: absolute;right:0; top:100px;">
        <nav class="sidebar dark">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li class="stick bg-red">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class=""></i>Service Call</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown" data-effect="slide">
                            <li><a href="servicecallnew.php">New Service</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service Call List</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>                            
                <li class="stick bg-red">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-sale"></i>File Maintenance</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown" data-effect="slide">
                        <li><a href="items.php?itd=&action">Items</a></li>
                        <li><a href="categories.php">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contractors.php">Contractors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="suppliers.php">Suppliers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                  <li class="stick bg-red">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-box-add"></i>Production</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">




                                <li><a href="estimatelist.php">Estimate / Quotation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="bomlist.php">Bill of Materials</a></li>
                                <li><a href="bomposting.php">BOM Posting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="issuancelist.php">Issuance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="adjplist.php">Adjustment</a></li>


                      </ul>
                  </li>


                  <li class="stick bg-red">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-box-add"></i>Inventory</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown"> 
                                <li><a href="receiving.php">Receiving</a></li>

                      </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="stick bg-red">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-printer"></i>Reports</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">

                             <!--   <li><a onClick="<?php echo "window.open('report_prod.php?type=estimate','mywindow3')"; ?>">Estimate / Quotation</a></li>
                                <li><a onClick="<?php echo "window.open('report_prod.php?type=bom','mywindow3')"; ?>">Bill of Materials</a></li>
                                <li><a onClick="<?php echo "window.open('report_prod.php?type=issuance','mywindow3')"; ?>">Issuance</a></li>
                                <li><a onClick="<?php echo "window.open('report_prod.php?type=adj','mywindow3')"; ?>">Adjustment</a></li>

                                <li><a onClick="<?php echo "window.open('rptinventory.php?','mywindow8','menubar=0,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=1000,height=500,left=0,top=0,screenX=50,screenY=100')"; ?>">Inventory</a></li>-->

                                    <li><a href="signspec.php">Sign Spec</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="warehouse.php">Warehouse</a></li>


                      </ul>
                  </li>
                                 <li class="stick bg-red"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
                <li class="stick bg-red"><a href="logout.php"><i class="icon-switch"></i>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Culd you please explain what you mean by "its not working" . Do you get error,  or no data etc.

Comment: there is no data coming out of the text box when I try the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need javascript to do this for you. What you need to do is fire an event that changes the text input value when there is a change in the selection. For example, for customer name you would do this:

```
$("#customer-name-select").change(function(){
  var customerName = $("option:selected").text();
  $("#customer-name-select").val(customerName);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have much knowledge in javascript. But thanks for the help. I'll start with this and research about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints.

1) Do your query above the doctype, not in the middle of the page.

2) Use an onchange attribute in your select menu to execute a javascript function that prepoulates the data.

3) Use `json_encode()` to convert the query result  to a json string, then assign that string to a javscript variable that your function can use to populate the fields.